# Nextjs 13 appDir Group route hydration error

Tags: next.js, routes, group, next.js13

Ive Just started learning nextjs 13, I'm using appDir experimental features.
The problem i face is a hydration error when i used layout page inside an route group. I've the following folder structure.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE8ZA.jpg)

***At post slug level, when i create a separate layout to avoid the blog layout to be shown, it shows error and at reload shows the blog layout initially then display post/slug layout both at same time.
Can anyone suggest how to use the route group in this situation + i also want category and pages (contact, about) route group like i  did with post grouping. Which is the correct approach to use it?

Nextjs route group cause hydration error

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this structure?

```
.
└── (blog)/
    ├── (Posts)/
    │   ├── [slug]/
    │   │   └── Page
    │   ├── Layout
    │   ├── Head
    │   └── Page
    └── (Studio)/
        ├── Layout
        ├── Head
        └── Page
```